# Chrome for Android doesn't correctly display vw

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, viewport-units

When I put  `<\meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>`
in the code of my site then 1 vw (viewport width) after rotating device from landscape to portrait or vice versa doesn't update.  For example if my phone screen is 640x360 and I open my site in portrait mode then 1vw = 1/360px but when I rotate it's still, but should be 1/640px.  In Firefox for Android everything seems correctly.  Is there any way to make it work without javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because it is not properly supported for Android yet.

http://caniuse.com/#search=Vw

Comment: Well, the future is nigh. I'm sure it will come around someday.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I put for viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: That doesn't matter. I put <\ because of without \ it didn't displayed here. Even with your code it still doesn't work correctly.  :/